# Is there a way to manage Azure Function Apps using Azure SDK?

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-sdk-.net

I would like to write a web app that allows users to write C# scripts and execute them using Azure Functions.

I checked Azure SDK documentation and didn't find any nuget packages for managing Function Apps.

Is there a way I can:

- retrieve list of available azure functions
- deploy azure function
- update azure function
- delete azure function

using Azure SDK?  If not, what would be another way to do it?

---

**Update on Jul 8, 2019**

I found List and Delete functions in Azure SDK (Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites):

List:
[Msdn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.iwebappsoperations.listfunctionswithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IWebAppsOperations_ListFunctionsWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

Delete
[Msdn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.iwebappsoperations.deletefunctionwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IWebAppsOperations_DeleteFunctionWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_)

I tested them and they work.
The problem is with Create method _CreateFunctionWithHttpMessagesAsync ([Msdn Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.management.websites.iwebappsoperations.createfunctionwithhttpmessagesasync?view=azure-dotnet#Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_IWebAppsOperations_CreateFunctionWithHttpMessagesAsync_System_String_System_String_System_String_Microsoft_Azure_Management_WebSites_Models_FunctionEnvelope_System_Collections_Generic_Dictionary_System_String_System_Collections_Generic_List_System_String___System_Threading_CancellationToken_))

It is not clear which parameters should be passed for it to work.
Currently I call it like this:

```
        var response = await webClient.WebApps.CreateFunctionWithHttpMessagesAsync(ResourceGroupName, FunctionAppName, functionName, new FunctionEnvelope());
```

In about 10-20s it returns error:
"Microsoft.Azure.Management.WebSites.Models.DefaultErrorResponseException : Operation returned an invalid status code 'InternalServerError'"

I think it is related to empty FunctionEnvelope. I tried passing various values, but none of them worked.

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK there is no SDK's available. But there are `REST API's` which let you perform all the above operations.

[List Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listfunctions)

[Delete Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/deletefunction)

For updating and Deployment you can make use of the `zip deployment` for Azure Functions.

Generate the `FunctionApp.zip` using the msbuild command pointing to your `csproj`->

```
/p:DeployOnBuild=true /p:DeployTarget=Package;CreatePackageOnPublish=true
```

The above will generate a zip file which can be used in the later part.

Now 2nd step is to  obtain the `Publish credentials` using this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/webapps/listpublishingcredentialsslot), if you get the response it will in the below class format

```
public class GetPublishCredentials
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Location { get; set; }
        public Properties Properties { get; set; }
    }
    public class Properties
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string PublishingUserName { get; set; }
        public string PublishingPassword { get; set; }
        public object PublishingPasswordHash { get; set; }
        public object PublishingPasswordHashSalt { get; set; }
        public object Metadata { get; set; }
        public bool IsDeleted { get; set; }
        public string ScmUri { get; set; }
    }
```

After obtaining the credentials, follow the below piece of code to `deploy` or `update` your Azure Functions

```
var base64Auth = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes
($"{functionCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName}:{functionCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword}"));
var stream = new MemoryStream(File.ReadAllBytes("zip file of azure function"));
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add("Authorization", "Basic " + base64Auth);
    var apiUrl = "https://" + parameters.FunctionAppName + ".scm.azurewebsites.net/api/zip/site/wwwroot";
    var httpContent = new StreamContent(stream);
    client.PutAsync(apiUrl, httpContent).Result;

}
```

Now your functionapp should be deployed.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Deploying using Zip Deploy makes sense, but before deploying I need to create the function.  I was able to find Create function on Azure SDK, but can't find the right arguments to pass to it.  See my update to my question.

Comment: @EricP like i said, create function app using code manually, and use `zip deploy`