# What is the equivalent of "az functionapp" in AzureRM?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-functions, azure-rm

My deployment script uses PowerShell with the AzureRM module. I am trying to find the equivalent of the following Azure CLI call. That call creates an Azure Function based on a Docker image.

```
az functionapp create --name <app_name> --storage-account  <storage_name>  --resource-group myResourceGroup --plan myPremiumPlan --deployment-container-image-name <docker-id>/mydockerimage:v1.0.0
```

Anybody has an idea what is the PowerShell/AzureRM equivalent of "az functionapp create"?

Comment: Why not install az module in your powershell ? Then you can use the command "az functionapp create".

Answer (score 1):

If your ideal goal is to deploy a function app, there are multiple ways to create one.

You can use the below ***AzureRm*** command to provision / create a new Function App

```
New-AzureRmResource -ResourceType ‘Microsoft.Web/Sites’ -ResourceName $functionAppName -kind ‘functionapp’ -Location $location -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -Properties @{} -force
```

Or You can use a `ARM Template` to deploy a function app - [Details](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-infrastructure-as-code)

Or you can use [Zip Deploy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56794077/is-there-a-way-to-manage-azure-function-apps-using-azure-sdk/56800864#56800864) to deploy your function app. -

Answer (score 1):

As HariHaran said, there are several ways to create new function app. But if you want to create function based on docker image, it may be difficult to implement if use "New-AzureRmResource". So I think you can install az module in powershell, you can continue use "az functionapp create" commmand, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/install-az-ps?view=azps-2.6.0#install-the-azure-powershell-module-1) tutorial to install it. But az module will not be compatible with AzureRM, so we'd better uninstall AzureRM before that, you can refer to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/migrate-from-azurerm-to-az?view=azps-2.6.0) page about the compatible of az module and AzureRM.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `New-AzFunctionApp` cmdlet which is part of the Az.Functions module. This module is currently in Preview.

```bsh
# First install PowerShell 6 or 7 from https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/releases

# To install the Az.Functions module, Open PowerShell and run:
Install-Module -Name Az.Functions -AllowPrerelease
```

Alternatively, you can download it from https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/Az.Functions/0.0.1-preview

For feedback and requests, please file an issue at https://github.com/Azure/azure-powershell/issues. Make sure you include in the title [Az.Functions]. Thanks!